# Send file using Axis2 1.7.4 from java client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, axis

I want to send a file using Axis2 1.7.4 to this endpoint https://cel.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantes?wsdl

Part of this code look like this:

```
OMFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
OMNamespace ns = factory.createOMNamespace("http://ec.gob.sri.ws.recepcion", "RecepcionComprobantesService");
   OMElement validarComprobante = factory.createOMElement("validarComprobante", ns);        
    ConfigurableDataHandler dataHandler = new ConfigurableDataHandler(new FileDataSource("file.xml"));
    dataHandler.setTransferEncoding("UTF-8");
    dataHandler.setContentType("txt/xml");
    OMText textData = factory.createOMText(dataHandler, false);       
    validarComprobante.addChild(textData);
    ...
       ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    ...
        OMElement response = client.sendReceive(validarComprobante);
```

I have a response from the server but the file is not accepted, because i get this message"FILES SUBMITTED DO NOT MEET THE SPECIFICATIONS ESTABLISHED: EXTENSION, CODIFICATION"

I read the documentation and the file is sent as Base64 encoded string, so i think that is the problem the content of the file is serialized and i dont know if is possible resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the WSDL description soap request body xml tag expecting base64 encoded string. So you have to read the file content,convert into base64 encoded string and try to pass that string value to xml tag.

You SOAP request should be similar to this

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ec="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.recepcion">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ec:validarComprobante>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <xml>VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IGRvY3VtZW50</xml>
          </ec:validarComprobante>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Axis encodes as base64, the web service receives only as a file.

Comment: Intercepting request soap message might help what is going wrong. I posted xml file as base64 encoded string to service and got error response "No information was found in the passkey tag". If I send plain text file as base64 encoded string got error "not able to convert to xml file". So based on errors analysis first case file validation passed. I suspect your request might not be going as base64.